# What technologies to use for web app hosting web page and logic to interrogate web page

Tags: java, dom, applet

I would like to create a web application that holds a web site in the right half of the screen, and some some widgets with logic in the left half.
For example, the user might specify that they want www.somesite.com to be analysed, so that site will show in the right half of my web page. I then want the user to be able to hit something like a 'record' button on the LHS, and that will then record what they do on the RHS (in the www.somesite.com) until the 'record' button is pressed again.

My first thought was an IFrame holding the web site (www.somesite.com in this case) and an applet in the LHS. The user hits record, the applet gets hold of the DOM for the web page and adds listeners on every textbox/button etc. I am not sure how the applet would get hold of the DOM (netscape.javascript.JSObject looked promising), but instead of fighting that, I thought I would ask if there is more appropriate technology other than IFrame/Applet? Any solution would have to be Java based. The above explanation of what the web app does is a vast over-simplification; I am only after help on the technologies that could be used to achieve something like it and not on the web app itself, which is really just for illustration purposes.

Many Thanks,
Paul

Comment: By 'record' do you mean simply to record what they did, or be able to record and replay what they did?  The first can be achieved by doing screen captures using Robot and turning that into a MOV or similar.  Perhaps the 'not over simplified' description would be better in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript/Java from your site will -not- be able to access properties of the DOM from another domain, whether in an iFrame or otherwise. This is a basic security principle that browsers implement, and rightly so.

See this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy